# MATLAB code in Overleaf compiles as Greek instead of English

Tags: overleaf, matlab

I'm writing a document using Overleaf. The main language I'm using is Greek. The Greek shows up fine but when I try to enter Matlab code using the package `listings`, it shows up as Greek in the compiled document instead of the English Matlab commands. Part of the code:

```
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
%matlab
\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}

\lstinputlisting{MyMatlabCode.m}
```

**Result:**

[image: matlab code result]

**How it should look like:**

[image: matlab code proper]

I used code from this question:
[What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document)

Comment: Please make this into something we can test. We don't have your m file

Comment: Might be an idea to wrap the input in the otherlanguage env given the mandatory arg is english

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I've found a solution but your comment helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using `\selectlanguage{}` and changing the language to English and then back to Greek again.

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\lstinputlisting{MyMatlabCode.m}
\selectlanguage{greek}
```

Comment: That is basically what the otherlanguage env does, you just don't what to manually insert the Greek at the end